# Flutter release apk not installing on Samsung A51

Tags: flutter

Any idea why flutter apk release file fails to install on a Samsung A51 device?

I've tried the following to solve the problem.

- Uninstall previous app
- From phone settings -> applications, and enabled the option 'Allow app from unknown source
- Update phone operating system to latest version

But the problem continued.

The error says: problem parsing package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the problem occurs when `targetSdkVersion` in `android/app/build.gradle` is less than the Android version installed on your phone.

**For example**

The `targetSdkVersion` is `29` but if your phone has installed Android 10 (SDK 30), it will not be able to install the file.

Comment: my targetSdkVersion is 31

Comment: I saw another answer that suggested adding this line in AndroidManifest.xml android:exported = "true" and it worked.